# Can you declare static local variables in a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr, c++23

Are you allowed to use `static` local variables in `constexpr` functions? For example:

```cpp
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

enum class axis {
    x, y, z
};

constexpr std::string_view axis_name(axis a) {
    // use static constexpr to avoid putting the table onto the stack
    static constexpr std::string_view names[] {
        "x", "y", "z"
    };
    return names[std::to_underlying(a)];
}

constexpr auto x_name = axis_name(axis::x);
```

GCC 12 fails to compile this with the error:

```
<source>:9:39: error: 'names' defined 'static' in 'constexpr' context
    9 |     static constexpr std::string_view names[] {
      |                                       ^~~~~
```

Other compilers allow it. What are the rules, and when is it allowed?

- can we use `static` in general, or
- just `static const`, or
- just `static constexpr`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code is okay since C++23, because the restrictions on `static constexpr` have been lifted.

### Relaxed Restrictions Since C++23

Until C++23, it was not only illegal to initialize a `static` local in a `constexpr` function, it was also illegal to declare one, even if control didn't flow through it.
For example:

```cpp
constexpr void foo() {
    if (false) {
        // allowed since C++23, otherwise ill-formed
        // ok because control never flows through x
        static int x;
    }
    // allowed since C++23, otherwise ill-formed
    // ok because static constexpr
    static constexpr int y = 0;
}
```

Disallowing `static constexpr` variables has always been an arbitrary restriction, lifted by [P2647 - Permitting `static constexpr` variables in `constexpr` functions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2647r1.html).

#### Compiler Support

To use this feature, you must use a recent compiler. As of the time of writing, this is the compiler support:

| C++23 Feature | Paper | GCC | Clang | MSVC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Permitting `static constexpr` variables in `constexpr` functions | [P2647R1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2647r1.html) | 13 | 16 | / |

*See also: [C++23 compiler support page on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/23)*

### Why Not Allow `static` In General?

It is unclear how `static` objects should behave at compile time, and how this could be implemented consistently across all compilers. For example, consider:

```cpp
constexpr std::size_t get_size() {
    static std::size_t s = 0;
    // different result each time get_size() is called
    return ++s;
}

// what are A and B??? B = 1, and B = 2 are both reasonable
template <std::size_t A = get_size(), B = get_size()>
constexpr std::size_t foo() { return A + B; }
```

It's easy to see `static` introduces a huge amount of problems and questions when used at compile time, so it will likely never be unrestricted. It breaks the assumption that `constexpr` functions are *pure* (have no side effects), and also makes it unsafe to *memoize* them (cache their results to call them less often).

#### About `static const`

`static const` is also problematic, because it could be initialized to a function argument:

```cpp
constexpr int remember_first_call(int x) {
    static const int y = x;
    return y;
}
```

This function will always return the argument that it has first been called with, which introduces an idea of "state" and "time" at compile time that shouldn't exist.
However, there is one exception to the rule for `static const`:

```cpp
constexpr int foo() {
    // allowed since C++23
    // ok because const integers are implicitly constexpr when possible
    static const int x = 3;
    return x;
}
```