# Why is the address of a constexpr local variable not a constant expression?

Tags: kotlin, c++, constexpr

The following constexpr function fails to compile:

```
constexpr void fnc()
{
    constexpr int i = 5;
    constexpr auto ptr = &i;
}
```

Why can't `ptr` be constexpr, considering that all the evaluations take place in a constexpr function and it works without declaring `ptr` constexpr?

Comment: you should include the error message in the question. The one I get here is rather clear about the "why" https://godbolt.org/z/5hzqszbP8. And its better to show the code that produces the error rather than code that others need to modify to reprodce the error (might seem like nitpicking, but every tiny detail that others have to edit is a potential source of confusion and misunderstanding that could be avoided easily)

Comment: The matter of the tag [tag:kotlin] appearing out of nowhere has been brought up on [Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427049/tags-on-a-question-dont-match-its-revision-history)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [error message from clang](https://godbolt.org/z/8ae8rbMvM) is clear enough:

> address of non-static constexpr variable 'i' may differ on each invocation of the enclosing function; add 'static' to give it a constant address

Comment: I read this message and still don't understand. Isn't &i a constant experssion, considering that it's been declared inside a constexpr function?

Comment: @Denis `constexpr` means that the function can be called in constexpr context, it does not mean that the function cannot also be called at runtime

Comment: @Denis constant expressions are supposed to have the same value given the same arguments, meaning they're supposed to be pure. Address of a local variable will be different on each invocation, so you should make it `static` to make sure you don't break this assumption.

Answer (score 9):

The fact that `i` is `constexpr` is irrelevant to the question whether its address is a constant. What `constexpr` does to a variable is explained in [[dcl.constexpr] p6](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6):

> In any `constexpr` variable declaration, the full-expression of the initialization shall be a [constant expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#def:constant_expression).

A `constexpr` variable is  merely initialized by a constant expression.
Each invocation of `fnc` is going to create a different object `i`, so the address may change.

An object needs to have static storage duration ([[expr.const] p13.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#13.3)) for its address to be a constant expression:

```cpp
static constexpr int i = 5;
constexpr auto ptr = &i; // OK
```

---

*Note: `static constexpr` is allowed in `constexpr` functions since C++23, see [Can you declare static local variables in a constexpr function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76547561/5740428)*

Answer (score 2):

The value of `ptr` is a *core constant expression*, meaning that it can be evaluated and used during constant evaluation, but it is not a *constant expression*. A constant expression is a core constant expression with some additional restrictions. Only a constant expression may be the final value of a `constexpr` variable or a non-type template parameter. (Non-type template parameters have some further restrictions, which I won't discuss here.)

A constant expression of pointer type can point to an object with static storage duration, or one past the end of an object with static storage duration, but it can't point to an object with any other storage duration. See [[expr.const]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#13).

The intuition is that a constant expression of pointer type must represent an address whose numerical value that is known at link time. (But not at compile time, which is why you can't use `reinterpret_cast` in constant expressions.) This restriction is artificial, and could be removed; however, it does prevent constexpr pointers from dangling:

```
constexpr void fnc()
{
    constexpr int i = 5;
    static constexpr auto ptr = &i;
}
```

If the above code could compile, then the second time `fnc` is called, `ptr` would be dangling since it would still point to the copy of `i` that was created the first time `fnc` was called.

The proposal [P2686R2](https://wg21.link/P2686R2) would make the OP's code valid, but the snippet above would still not be valid: constexpr pointers/references with automatic storage duration would be allowed to point/refer to objects with automatic storage duration declared earlier in the same function or to objects  with static storage duration, but constexpr pointers/references with static storage duration would only be allowed to point/refer to objects with static storage duration. Addresses of objects with automatic storage duration would still not be allowed as template parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to provide an intuitive explanation, since others have covered the [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) aspects quite well.

`i` is `constexpr`, but it is also odr-used, meaning that it has to be given an address in memory.  That's object identity.  Each distinct instance needs to have a distinct identity (during its lifetime).

Consider:

```
constexpr void fnc(int depth = 1, int const* ptr2 = nullptr)
{
    constexpr int i = 5;
    const auto ptr = &i;

    static_assert(ptr != ptr2);
    if (depth > 0) fnc(depth - 1, &i);
}
```

When you call `fnc()`, depth == 1 and ptr2 == nullptr

The recursive call has depth == 0 and ptr2 equal to the address of `i` in the caller.

Should `ptr` and `ptr2` compare equal?  C++ says "no", each is the address of a different `const int` object.  But that also means the pointer value isn't a compile-time constant.